# Select all upcoming events where a user participate in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with sql that is suppose to select all upcoming events where a specific user participate in. This is sample how my tables looks like

**events**

```
  id  |      timestamp      |  name  | deleted
 200  | 2014-04-01 14:00:00 | test 1 |    0
 201  | 2013-06-30 20:50:00 | test 2 |    0
 205  | 2014-04-02 09:00:00 | test 3 |    1
 210  | 2014-04-03 08:55:34 | test 4 |    0
```

**responses**

```
  id  | user | event |      timestamp      | canceled
 1001 |  50  |  201  | 2013-06-01 10:15:39 |    0
 1002 |  23  |  205  | 2014-02-15 09:32:00 |    0
 1003 |  50  |  210  | 2014-02-15 10:00:00 |    0
 1004 |  50  |  210  | 2014-02-16 20:00:00 |    1
 1005 |  50  |  200  | 2014-02-16 20:05:40 |    0
```

To explain the structure: If an admin deletes an event the deleted value of the event is set to 1. If an user registers to an event, a new row in `responses` is added with the user id, the event id, the current time and canceled = 0. He is also able to cancel his registration. In this case a new row is added to `responses` with canceled = 1. So on each change of the registration status of an user to an event a new row is added. It's possible that a users registered for an event, than cancel his registration and than register a second time for the same event.

Now I want to select all upcoming events where the user with the id 50 is registered (and has not canceled his registration). This should be the result:

```
event.id |   event.timestamp   | responses.id
   200   | 2014-04-01 14:00:00 |     1005
```

At the moment i'm using to SELECT statements and php to get the result shown above.
EDIT
this is what I do at the moment:
first I do

```
"SELECT id,timestamp FROM events WHERE timestamp>NOW() AND deleted=0"
```

than I run a php foreach loop to perform this statement for each upcoming event

```
"SELECT id,canceled FROM responses WHERE user = 50 AND event=$event->id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
```

If a row exists I check with php if canceled is 0.

How to solve the problem with a single SELECT statement?

Comment: Can you post the SELECT statements you are currently using?

Comment: It's better - easier to read for one - if you edit the original question and add new text.

Comment: Why would you add a new row for a user cancellation rather than update the flag on the current record?  That is typically how flags such as these are used.

Comment: Because the original table has some more cols like `paid`. So I want to know each single action a user has done and when.

Comment: @user3430542 So why would having an additional paid column require you to add a new row? In fact, the more columns like that you have the more reason to have the data in a single row, so you don't end up with incopmplete data across a number of rows (i.e. one row with sign up, one row with payment, another row with cancellation, etc.). Querying a table structured in such a manner to get an authoritative view of that state of a registration will become very painful.

Comment: @user3430542 If you need to keep a timestamp of each action, then have a datetime column for each action, perhaps even removing the flag altogether since the presence of a non-null value would serve the same purpose. Continuing with your approach will mean you will need to perform group aggregations for all lookup queries on this table to get a full view of the status, and then filter the records after the aggregation using `HAVING`.  This is a very inefficient way to lookup this data.

Comment: that right, but there are multiple admins an each can edit if the user has paid. All events are paid with cash and the paid col is not only a flag, it's value is the user ID where the cash is at the moment. I want to track who has the cash. For example: The user gives the cash to Admin A, but Admin C collects the cash from all users. Now Admin A gives the cash to B and B than to C. All steps have to been tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM events e 
  JOIN responses r
    ON r.event_id = e.id
  JOIN
     ( SELECT user
            , event_id
            , MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
         FROM responses 
        GROUP
           BY user
            , event_id
     ) x
    ON x.user = r.user
   AND x.event_id = r.event_id
   AND x.max_timestamp = r.timestamp
 WHERE e.timestamp > NOW() 
   AND r.user = 50 
   AND r.canceled = 0 
   AND e.deleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subselect the `MAX(canceled)` in order to see if the user canceled the registration.
Something similar to:

```
SELECT resp.user, events.id, events.name, events.timestamp AS event_time
FROM events
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, event, MAX(canceled) canceled FROM responses GROUP BY user, event) resp
ON (events.id=resp.event)
WHERE events.timestamp>NOW() AND events.deleted=0 AND resp.canceled=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick

You will select the responses, filtered by the USER name, and join the event that those responses belong to.

```
SELECT * FROM `responses`
JOIN `events` ON (
    `events`.`id` = `responses`.`event` AND
    `events`.`deleted` = 0
)
WHERE `responses`.`user` = :USER AND
`responses`.`canceled` = 0
```

The reason for selecting the `responses` is because it holds the discriminating column, the `user`.

Comment: While this query is fine and all, this still will not solve the OP's problem with a change to the way the responses are tracked.  For example, your query would return response id 1003 and 1005 for user 50.  This is because he still has the uncanceled row associated with event 210 which would show up in this query.

Answer (score 0):

The eaiset way is to change your approach of adding a separate "cancelled event" record to the response table.  This basically makes no sense.  In order for a user to cancel an event, I am assuming you have to know the specific response id to be cancelled.  You should update the cancelled flag to 1 in such a case rather than adding a new row to the table.  That makes your query as simple as:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.`timestamp`,
    r.id
FROM
    events AS e
    INNER JOIN responses AS r
        ON e.id = r.event
WHERE
    r.user = ?
    AND r.canceled = 0
    AND e.deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT e.id,e.name,r.userid,r.cancelled,MAX(cancelled) as flag
from event e 
join responses r
on r.event_id=e.id where
e.deleted=0  group by userid  order by e.id) as users where flag=0;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I know the user id and I only want to select the events where this user registered for. Your code also fails if the user registered, than cancelled and than registers a second time

Comment: select event_id,cancelled from responses where userid = '2'  order by timestamp desc limit 1 ; 
You can check if the cancelled is 0 or 1 in your php.